# RSS-like feed for calendar events in Plone

Tags: plone, google-calendar-api, icalendar, vcalendar

Is there any kind of standard or recommendation synching calendar events between CMS sites?

- Plone site would produce this feed from its Event content type
- Other site(s) could embed this feed to their own calendars, so that one could merge events from many different sources (Google Calendar, to name one)
- The feed update would be automatic over HTTP and one would not need to run manual calendar event export/import dump cycle

Comment: I think you are having day dreams...I am not aware of such a plugin or solution. In particular merging calendars, dates etc. is pretty complex - especially when it comes to syncing conflicts which usually require manual interaction and an  intellectual solution

Comment: There won't be conflicts because all events are separate (they are events, not appointments) I know Google Calendar can export/import feeds.

Comment: If there is not existing solution I'd like to get pointers what protocols there exist for exchanging this kind of information.

Comment: Is CalDAV what you seek (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mikko, as of Plone 3.3, PLIP 246 was merged, so Collections of Events should expose an iCal feed, which you can access by appending ics_view.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation how this feature should work ormeven in which package it resides

Comment: It lives in ATCT 1.3.1 and higher (per the PLIP). Not sure really how it works, to be honest.

Comment: OK, it is really not documented, but I believe you get an iCal file by appending ics_view onto any event or Collection.

Comment: Documented now here http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/events.html#ical-export

Comment: The above link is broken, the equivalent is here in [docs.plone.org](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/events.html#ical-export)  But there is a newer dexterity solution happening in [plone.app.event](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.event/tree/master/plone/app/event/ical)